# httplib.HTTPSConnection timeout when connecting to Amazon Web Services

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto, httplib

I've followed all the instructions for installing and enabling django-storages and boto in my app to upload files to S3.  (As this application is intended for deployment on Heroku, I'm using virtualenv to manage dependencies.)

For local development I've put all my credentials in ~/.bash_profile:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxx
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=yyyy
export S3_BUCKET_NAME=zzzz
```

So, great, but then this:

```
> python manage.py shell
>>> import boto
>>> conn = boto.connect_s3()
>>> conn.get_all_buckets()
```

Produces these debugging messages and this error:

```
2012-06-04 23:17:34,432 [DEBUG] boto: path=/
2012-06-04 23:17:34,432 [DEBUG] boto: auth_path=/
2012-06-04 23:17:34,433 [DEBUG] boto: Method: GET
2012-06-04 23:17:34,433 [DEBUG] boto: Path: /
2012-06-04 23:17:34,433 [DEBUG] boto: Data: 
2012-06-04 23:17:34,433 [DEBUG] boto: Headers: {}
2012-06-04 23:17:34,433 [DEBUG] boto: Host: s3.amazonaws.com
2012-06-04 23:17:34,433 [DEBUG] boto: establishing HTTPS connection: host=s3.amazonaws.com, kwargs={'timeout': 2}
2012-06-04 23:17:34,433 [DEBUG] boto: Token: None
2012-06-04 23:17:34,436 [DEBUG] boto: StringToSign:
GET


Tue, 05 Jun 2012 03:17:34 GMT
2012-06-04 23:17:36,900 [DEBUG] boto: encountered SSLError exception, reconnecting
2012-06-04 23:17:36,901 [DEBUG] boto: establishing HTTPS connection: host=s3.amazonaws.com, kwargs={'timeout': 2}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "../venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 346, in get_all_buckets
    response = self.make_request('GET', headers=headers)
  File "../venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 454, in make_request
    override_num_retries=override_num_retries)
  File "../venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 838, in make_request
    return self._mexe(http_request, sender, override_num_retries)
  File "../venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 803, in _mexe
    raise e
SSLError: _ssl.c:484: The handshake operation timed out
```

What I can't understand is that using the SAME EXACT CREDENTIALS I am able to connect without any problems using a GUI on my Mac to browse S3.  I can list all the buckets.  I can get into bucket zzzz.  I can upload a file to it.  I can download it again.  I can delete it.  All is well.  But no matter what I try through Boto it times out with no further comment.

**Why is boto timing out in my local environment?**

### Update

I was able to narrow down the below to:

```
>>> import httplib
>>> h1 = httplib.HTTPSConnection('s3.amazonaws.com')
>>> h1.request ("GET", "/")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 958, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 992, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 954, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 814, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 776, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1161, in connect
    self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 382, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 143, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 306, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
error: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

Whereas:

```
>>> h1 = httplib.HTTPSConnection('google.com')
>>> h1.request ("GET", "/")
>>> r1 = h1.getresponse()
>>> print  r1.status, r1.reason
301 Moved Permanently
```

What is it about AWS that is freaking httplib.HTTPSConnection out?

(I know the request above isn't a correct and complete AWS request, but I simplified it just to try to get a response from the server.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that the problem is with my home internet! When I took my laptop elsewhere to work, the problem did not repeat itself. So the problem has nothing to do with Django, Boto, AWS, S3, SSL, Python, or anything remotely interesting, and everything to do with how much Time Warner Cable sucks. Can you believe it?!

Comment: Did you ever figure out why this is? I had to make a file /etc/boto.cfg and place `[Boto]\nis_secure = false` into it to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this line in your debug output:

```
boto: establishing HTTPS connection: host=s3.amazonaws.com, kwargs={'timeout': 2}
```

I assume that you have put something like this in your boto config file:

```
[Boto]
http_socket_timeout = 2
```

Is that correct?  If so, what happens if you increase this timeout to 10 seconds or 20 seconds.  Do you still get the timeout?

Comment: [Boto]
    debug = 2
    http_socket_timeout = 2
    num_retries = 0

Yeah, I did that b/c I was too impatient to wait longer for it to fail once I saw that it was failing consistently.  :-(

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens if you try it without SSL (e.g. boto.connect_s3(is_secure=False)?  BTW, I tried the exact same thing locally and it worked fine.  If it works without SSL, perhaps there is a problem with openssl install?

Comment: I'm not sure where that call is, to be honest... I didn't actually write any boto code.  I enabled it in my settings.py and made this one change to the relevant model:  filepath = models.FileField(storage=S3BotoStorage(bucket=os.getenv('S3_BUCKET_NAME')), ...).